# If else condition in a php script

Tags: php, css, if-statement

I am trying to modify [this](http://codecanyon.net/item/php-search-engine/2342871) search engine script provided by codecanyon. Here I can see a code like

```
<div class="{$contentClass}">

   <div class="resultarea" style="width:55%;float:left;">
      {$content}
   </div>

</div>
```

Here I need to set the width as 100% if $contentClass="mainpage"  and would like to set the width as 55% for other pages.

I have tried the following code

```
<div class="{$contentClass}">

<div class="resultarea" <?php if ($contentClass=="mainpage"){?> style="width:100%;float:left;" <?php }else{?>style="width:100%;float:left;"<?php} ?>>
    {$content}
</div>
```

I think PHP codes is not working here , I can print the value of contentClass with out providing the php echo statement as {$contentClass}. I am not sure about the framework used here , please help me to solve this issue.

Please check my work [here](https://mediahost.in/)

Comment: what's the output you see in the page source? you also didn't changed `width` value at your condition

Comment: This isn't PHP as such, it's a templating engine of some sort. From the syntax, it could be [Smarty](http://smarty.net).

Comment: {$variable}: here parenthesis is used to enclose pgp variable withing a echo or string output statement. What you are trying is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time , is there any chance to implement such an if else statement there ??

Comment: @IMSoP I didn't work with smarty but as I know php template engines accept raw php codes too.

Comment: I have updated the question with my work url , plz check it there

Comment: @UdayHiwarale that's true but he didn't use `{$variable}` form in his `if` condition.

Comment: @revo It's entirely up to the template engine what syntax it accepts. The simplest template syntax is one which simply substitutes variables wherever placeholders appear.

Comment: @user2923383: Try something like this:

    <div class="resultarea" 
       {if $contentClass=="mainpage"}
          style="width:100%;float:left;"
       {else}
          style="width:50%;float:left;"
       {/if}>

Comment: @IMSoP does smarty accept raw PHP?

Comment: It is not smary I have tried smarty if else statement there

Comment: @revo Smarty2 has a `{php}` tag which can be disabled for security; Smarty3 removed it. More importantly, it has an `{if}` tag, so there is no need to break out of the template syntax for such simple logic.

Comment: @user2923383 Well, it's definitely not raw PHP either, so you'll have to ask the author of the script what syntax is accepted.

Comment: Well, if there's no way to find out the template engine logic, then you should solve this with css.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
<div class="resultarea" <?php if ($contentClass=="mainpage"){?> style="width:100%;float:left;" <?php }else{?>style="width:50%;float:left;"<?php} ?>>
```

If you look at the CSS inside your else block, you'll see that you were setting the width to 100%. Basically, your CSS is the same, regardless of whether `$contentClass=="mainpage"` or not.

Your IF statement doesn't actually do anything:

```
<?php if ($contentClass=="mainpage"){?> 
    style="width:100%;float:left;" 
<?php }else{?>
    style="width:100%;float:left;"
<?php} ?>>
```

Comment: If you look at the existing code (e.g. `{$contentClass}`), it's clear that this is not a plain PHP file, so there is no reason to assume that this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Given that $contentClass is a variable, you've got to use "echo" command.
Also, since there is an excluding condition (do the following everywhere except the mainpage), it will be reasonable to use $contentClass!="mainpage".

The code will look like

```
<?php
if ($contentClass!="mainpage") 
  {
   echo 'style="width:55%;float:left;"';
  }
?>
```

Comment: If you look at the existing code (e.g. `{$contentClass}`), it's clear that this is not a plain PHP file, so there is no reason to assume that this will work.